# My angular 4 + mvc web app not working in Internet explorer.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, internet-explorer

I have developed a application with angular 4 and mvc but I am facing issue with browser. It perfectly works for the chrome, firefox and any other browser except Internet explorer. Can anyone suggest me possible ways to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

In your root source folder there is a file called "polyfills.ts". This contains some commented out lines for libraries that are required for Angular to work correctly in Internet Explorer.

Open the file in your editor and uncomment the lines that are related to IE9, IE10 and IE11 (they are near the top) and, rebuild and it should work :)

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried and didn't work , plus any errors you see in the IE Dev Tools please? That would give us a better chance of helping you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your angular project, you have a polyfills.ts file in  that uncomment the following lines,

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';
```